# Autocomplete show entire list on down arrow key

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have applied autocomplete plugin on a textbox like this.

```
var model = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                model.push({ Label: data[i].ModelName, Value: data[i].CodeModel });
}
 var modelData = model;
 $('#tbmodele').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    response($.map(modelData, function (value) {
                        if (value.Label.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
                            return {
                                label: value.Label,
                                vvalue: value.Value
                            };
                        }
                    }));
                },              
                select: function (e, i) {
                    populateOtherFields(i.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                open: function () {
                    $scope.isModelDropdownOpen = true;
                },              
                minLength: 0,
                scroll: true
 });
```

Now I want to open the autocomplete list on pressing down arrow key of that text field.

Can anyone please suggest how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the down arrow key to autocomplete's `search` method:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#tbmodele', function() {
   $('#tbmodele').autocomplete('search', '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Further reply to this one as the accepted answer will always pop it up on any key press. To limit this behaviour to only work with key down and when the input field is empty, use this code:

```
$('#tbmodele').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40 && $(this).val().length==0) {
    $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
  }
});
```